# ROC curve and confusion matrix in classifier performance evaluation

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data-mining, roc

I applied  two different classifiers against the same validation set. It turns out that classifier A is better than classifier B in terms of ROC curve. However, classifier B is better than classifier A in terms of confusion matrix. How to explain this kind of contradiction?

Comment: Add data and graphs. Otherwise it's difficult to know what you mean. Also, what does "better in terms of confusion matrix" mean? You can order them by accuracy, or f-score, or precision, or recall, or sensitivity, or specificity, ....

Comment: You still haven't told us what it means to be "better" in terms of confusion matrix. There isn't only one way to compare confusion matrices!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A [ROC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receiver_operating_characteristic) curve shows you performance across a range of different classification thresholds and a [confusion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) only shows you one (typically when $Pr(y > .5)$).

Comment: In general, which metric, ROC or confusion matrix is a more reasonable one?

Comment: The ROC curve subsumes the confusion matrix. It is not as easily interpretable though.